# Multiple Custom Lists Single Form : New / Edit / View

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I am developing Sharepoint site for my Organisation. We are using Custom Lists for storing data.

I have a requirement now, to have only one New Form and One Edit Form for 3 lists. And one will be as a Header and the other two will be details.

If I name those 3 lists as **lstHeader, lstDetails1, lst Details2** (The Names are for this illustration only).

Now when the user starts adding of the records, the New Form should be having the **lstHeader** feilds and also the **lstDetails1** & **lstDetails2** fields. The data entered into the feilds should be saved in the respective lists along with one header feild. More like a Header / Detail form.

I browsed for this on the web but the posts I cam across specified that this can be done using visual studio, but I could not find any details on how to do so.

Any help on this  (pointers to articles that describe this solution in a step by step manner) is much awaited and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint 2013, you can create the form using HTML and JS and then associate it to the lists you want. There are plenty references saying how to create a SharePoint App on the web, but you can use:

- SharePoint Hosted App with AngularJS: http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/10/sharepoint-hosted-app-with-angularjs-for-mvc-javascript/
- Create a SharePoint Hosted App with Visual Studio: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/04/30/sharepoint-hosted-app-visual-studio.aspx
- Get started creating SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-ins: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx

with that said, you will only need coding skills to address your business requirement.